# No dependency HTML (CSS, JS) Rendering Engine

Tags: javascript, html, c++, rendering, awesomium

***I am using c++***

I am developing an in-game ui to be used in any arbitrary process that I want it to run on. Basically I want it to be able to work on any application that uses lets say DX9.

But that really isn't my question, what I want to be able to do is use HTML and (JS, CSS) to render my UI.

I would love to use something like Awesomium or the Chromium Embedded Framework but both seem to require you to have 5+ dependencies (dlls, etc) and require you to have to have them the same directory as the parent application.

Now because I will be injecting a dll that does this, I don't exactly want to or have a way to get the dependencies in the right location for it to work properly.

*I definitely do not want all the misc dependencies to be lying in the same folder as the target process*

I would like to use something that is possibly either a static lib or one dll as a dependency.

The other issue is, it seems that CEF and Awesomium are some of the only ones that actually have a decent callback system between javascript and C++.

I guess what I need to know is, Is their a way to keep all the Awesomium  / CEF dependencies in one folder and reference them from any application? Or are there any better solutions to use.

*I have also seen Sciter, which seems to be a good option, but uses something similar to JavaScript but not exactly, which is not ideal.*

A bit more info, based on these remarks :

> The directory from which the application loaded.
>   The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
>   The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
>   The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
>   The current directory.
>   The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

Dlls should not be too much of an issue, but I'll have to look into some of the other stuff.

Comment: These requirements seem eccentric at best. But if you really want to get a browser running in a C++ application on Windows without any external components, you can embed the local Internet Explorer version using the IWebBrowser2 COM control.

Comment: @MrEricSir From what I can tell this gives me no way to actually render it and gives me limited control if that of javascript. I don't mind if it has dependencies, I just would like to find a solution where all dependencies could be stored in one shared location.

Comment: I have done some tests and it seems that I can put all the dependencies in  certain directories like Windows, System etc... I'm going to check about the path Var

Comment: A side comment: Awesomium is pretty outdated and fails to update to a newer rendering engine, see [this community discussion](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/7255/is-awesomium-dead-now.html)

Comment: @Sjoerd222888 I have got sciter to work very well, it has been in development for 8+ years and the main programmer would always respond to help threads within minutes.